Lost 2fa, no seed
three years ago I created a 2FA wallet with Google Authenticator (when there was no option to back up codes). Unfortunately, I lost my mobile device and I don’t have the seed either. I already know that there is no way to recover the wallet using the private keys, and I also tried to contact TrustedCoin to reset the 2FA. However, their policy does not allow for resetting the code (even though I’ve read on some forums about people who managed to reset their 2FA by providing proof of identity).
I am writing this post here in hopes that someone can give me an email address for a developer or someone who works at TrustedCoin, or that someone can point me to a forum where I could get help, as my only hope is to get in direct contact with someone from their team. (I have already sent many emails to userhelp@trustedcoin.com, but they have stopped responding). I have access to my wallet, I just can’t spend the funds.

recovering Google authenticator when phone lost
